# Chromium Loading Mod_Rewrite'd Pages Twice

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, chromium

When I Mod_Rewrite a page, Chromium will load the page twice. Other browsers like Firefox only load it once. I have seen a tun of posts saying Chromium has trouble with empty GET requests, but that doesn't seem to apply to me as the only thing I'm returning is a basic static HTML page with only the count of requests in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>TITLE</title></head><body>3</body></html>
```

The 3 indicates the count of total page loads (and is pretty much the only dynamic value in this)

When I load pages in Firefox or using wget in the terminal it returns `1, 2, 3, 4, 5...` as it should, while Chromium returns `1, 3, 5, 7, 9...`.

I don't really get how Chromium is supposed to know when a page is Mod_Rewritten. (There should be no difference in output should there? )

Also in case it matters, these are the HTTP response headers.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 13 Oct 2013 17:53:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 76
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=86
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching through the access log I saw Chromium was also trying to load `favicon.ico` which obviously got rewritten too and thus caused a second page load.